# What is the correct/sercure way to send requests to ArangoDB?

Tags: php, request, arangodb

It's my first time working with databases, and I'm not sure how I should approach this.
I want to create a web app, and this web app should request information from ArangoDB. This web app will have, among other things, sensitive user information.

I wrote some JS code in the front-end, but quickly realized that in order to request an authentication JWT token from Arango API, I'm exposing the root user and root password to anyone auditing the code.

```
await getAuthenticationToken('username here', 'password here');
```

The second important observation is when saving the JWT token in a cookie, this cookie can be accessed programatically, and this may be a serious security issue.

I've read that I need to store the JWT token string inside a http cookie so that it can't be accessed.

Does this API communication code belong in the back-end, or can I have for example a php script accessed via frontend JS, that handles only the credentials/authentication token/requests?

Someone suggested adding multiple users to the database. I get the feeling it's a bad idea to allow random users direct but limited permission to access the database, even if fine grained control of these permissions is possible. Surely creating users for the database is only a feature for employees not random app users. -- Or am I missing something here?

Comment: One way is to set Foxx configuration settings that contain API keys, and they can default to values like '12345' but when you open the configuration settings, you can put in a 120 random character string if you want to be that secure.  This way each installation of the Foxx service can have it's own API keys. You can also implement multiple API keys that provide different levels of access, or use those keys to create/manage internal users that are stored in a collection, with encrypted passwords.

Comment: @DavidThomas - you should make that an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @kerry Yup, thanks

Answer (score 1):

One way is to set Foxx configuration settings that contain API keys, and they can default to values like `12345` but when you open the configuration settings, you can put in a 120 random character string if you want to be that secure.

This way each installation of the Foxx service can have it's own API keys.

You can also implement multiple API keys that provide different levels of access, or use those keys to create/manage internal users that are stored in a collection, with encrypted passwords.